# So there is CM_satisfaction coulmn that contains different values like Fully Dissatisfied,Somewhat Satisfied and Fully_Satisfied in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

So there is CM_satisfaction column that contains different values like Fully Dissatisfied, Somewhat Satisfied, and Fully_Satisfied in pandas. I need how many voters where Fully_Satisfied. I have found out that using

```
Fully_Satisfied=survey[survey["CM_satisfaction"] == "Fully_Satisfied"]
```

Next, I need to find how many voters were Fully_Satisfied by each day of sample collection.I have also found out that

```
day-wise=only_date_and_cm.groupby("collection_date").count()
```

The result I got is

collection_date       CM_satisfaction

2020-08-24            146

2020-08-25             95

2020-08-26              59

2020-08-27              54

2020-08-28            92

2020-08-29              73

2020-08-30            65

2020-08-31           62

2020-09-01          75

Now the main part
For each day of sample collection, determine the proportion of respondents who were fully satisfied with the performance of the CM. So if there were a total of 1000 samples on day 1 and 300 out of those said they were fully satisfied, then our answer for that day would be 0.3.

I have also found total votes on each day

```
day_wise_vote=survey.collection_date.value_counts()
day_wise_vote
```

2020-08-24    1479

2020-08-25     998

2020-08-28     761

2020-08-27     665

2020-08-29     620

2020-09-01     607

2020-08-26     598

2020-08-30     582

2020-08-31     557

Now how do I find the proportion of respondents who were fully satisfied with the performance of the CM day wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply do:

```
day_wise_proportion = day_wise.astype(float) / day_wise_vote
```

The idea is that when you divide a pandas Series by another (of the same length and index), python will divide the values row by row.

---

It also looks like you create many intermediate dataframes.
You could do somethink like that, which will be faster and clearer :

```
survey['Fully_Satisfied'] = (survey["CM_satisfaction"] == "Fully_Satisfied").astype(float)
day_wise = survey.groupby("collection_date").agg({'Fully_Satisfied': 'sum',
                                                  'CM_satisfaction': 'count'})
day_wise.rename(columns={'CM_satisfaction': 'vote'}, inplace=True)

day_wise['proportion'] = day_wise['Fully_Satisfied'] / day_wise['vote']
```

Comment: 2020-08-24 00:00:00 2020-08-25 00:00:00 2020-08-26 00:00:00 2020-08-27 00:00:00 2020-08-28 00:00:00 2020-08-29 00:00:00 2020-08-30 00:00:00 2020-08-31 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 CM_satisfaction
collection_date          
2020-08-24 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-08-25 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-08-26 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-08-27 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-08-28 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-08-29 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN I m getting this result

Comment: maybe this happens because da_wise and day_wise_vote are not created the same way.
You can try : 


`day_wise_vote = survey.groupby('collection_date').count()`

Comment: survey['Fully_Satisfied'] = (survey["CM_satisfaction"] == "Fully_Satisfied").astype(float)
day_wise = survey.groupby("collection_date").agg({'Fully_Satisfied': 'sum',
                                                  'CM_satisfaction': 'count'})
day_wise.rename(columns={'CM_satisfaction': 'vote'}, inplace=True)

day_wise['proportion'] = day_wise['Fully_Satisfied'] / day_wise['vote'] This one worked thanks